# count the usage of a module type

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How to know how many copies of a module type are in use in all positions?

I have to know it and use it in my module script.
Because the module has a JavaScript code, and it should print just one time.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

let assume that It's login module

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'login' );
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $module );
echo '</pre>'
```

which will return

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 18
    [title] => Login Form
    [module] => mod_login
    [position] => left
    [content] => 
    [showtitle] => 1
    [control] => 
    [params] => greeting=1
                name=0
    [user] => 0
    [name] => login
    [style] => 
)
```

Looking at the above result you can develop your logic. **[Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModule)**